# 3D visualisation and post analysis tool

Tags: visualization, data-analysis, plotting

I am looking for a 3D plotting and post analysis tool, specifically which can generate figures like the following. It is preferred the tool has a Linux distribution. The figure is copied from [here](https://www.pnas.org/content/115/21/5397#sec-3). [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found that such graphs can be created with the software [Origin](https://www.originlab.com/). It is a cheap commercial software (student version: $69 per year). It's certainly worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly is an excellent tool for 2D and 3D data. It is quite simple to use with python as well.

https://plotly.com/python/